# "from" import works differently

Tags: python

I have this code in my Python code (`settings.py` is located in the `PROJECT` dir):

```
import PROJECT.settings
...
if PROJECT.settings.BASE_DIR:
   ...
```

which works fine. I'd say I could rewrite to this:

```
from PROJECT import settings
...
if settings.BASE_DIR:
   ...
```

But that gives an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'BASE_DIR'`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Note that if this is Django (as it seems to be) you should always import settings via `from django.conf import settings`, not directly from your project.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks. I am trying to deploy my site now, but am under time pressure. I will update the code to be correct later.

Comment: Well, apart from anything else, this fixes your problem, so you should probably do it now.

Comment: It doesn't fix my problem. I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `from parent import name` format first looks for names in the `module` namespace (set in `__init__.py` or anything that added that name to the `parent` module).

In your case, the `__init__.py` file in `PROJECT` has set `settings` to `None`. It is this name that is found before any contained modules.

The `import parent.name` form will only look for modules in a package, not for names defined in the `parent` module.

Comment: Thanks, although `__init.py__` is basically empty, I reckon some other stuff is going on (I am using Django) that sets it to `None`. I always thought the two were identical, but apparently not.